# Default value for a reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to make last argument in my function to be a default argument and the type of this argument is `*&` (reference to pointer). For some reason this doesn't work for me:

```
template<class T>
void f(T*& = nullptr);
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from '`nullptr`' to '`T *&`'

How to get around this?

Comment: You cannot have a reference to a literal value.

Comment: Too mny unncssry abbrvs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you need to call this function with `nullptr` (which means *"I don't have a value to pass to the function, but want to call it anyway"*), then you would want to take the argument per `T**`.

See ***[How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224)*** for more on passing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If the argument is optional, it needs to be a pointer, not a reference.

```
template<class T>
void f(T** const = 0);
```

If you want the call-style to be pass-by-reference, then you need a forwarder, not a default argument.

```
template<class T>
void f_impl(T** const);

template<class T>
void f( T*& arg ) { return f_impl(&arg); }

template<class T>
void f( void ) { return f_impl<T>(0); }
```

If you want to avoid null checks and just discard assignment to the parameter when no parameter is given, do this:

```
template<class T>
void f(T*&); 

template<class T>
void f( void ) { T* unused = 0; return f(unused); }
```

Note that `T` in the no-argument version is a non-deduced context, but so was the original when no parameter was provided.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It certainly brings something new for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have an l-value reference to a pointer there, so you'll need to default it to an l-value. Since l-values can't be `nullptr` (it's an r-value), either you'll need to change the function to take an r-value:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T const* const& = nullptr)
```

or, define some l-value pointer for all types `T`.

```
template <typename T>
struct NullPtr
{
    static T const* lvalue = nullptr;
};

template <typename T>
void f(T const*& = NullPtr<T>::lvalue)
```

but I can't imagine any reason you'd actually want an l-value to default to that.

Comment: Your wrapper is a good syntactic idea, but I am afraid it doesn't add any semantic benefit. There is a reason why non-const references don't bind to rvalues, especially literals, and trying to hack this is pointless :)

Comment: @Peter thanks for your answer. Your second example doesn't wont to work for me. I'm getting an error:Error 1 error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'Nullptr<T>::value' to 'int *&'

Comment: @Armen: My best guess (assuming he *really* wants an lvalue) is that the parameter is an out parameters, and the default parameter is used when you don't need the out parameters. Here, NullPtr<T>::lvalue acts as a "sink" for the out parameter.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, I thought that too, but came up with a different solution

Comment: @Tinwcd: My bad, I'm using g++ 4.5, which doesn't have nullptr so I only tried it with 0 in its place. You probably need const in the type, I'll change this in my answer.